# non-linear ordinary differential equation (Jacobi's?)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am working on some firm optimization problem and got to the following differential equation.

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{(y-x)(1-y)}{(c-x)(1-2y+x)}$ with $x,y \in [0, 1]$ and c is a constant with $0<c\leq1$.

I know the obvious solution $y=1$ but I was wondering if there is any other solutions. Also I am looking for a generic solution that depends on any $c$ within the specified interval.

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't solutions depend on $c$? And also show some effort if you seek not to be downvoted.

Comment: Yes I initially thought they are similar but the other topic is only a special case when c=1.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{(y-x)(1-y)}{(c-x)(1-2y+x)}$$
Let $u(x)=1-2y+x\qquad;\qquad y=\frac12(1+x-u)$
$$\frac12(1-u')=\frac{(1-x-u)(1-x+u)}{4(c-x)u}$$
$$uu'=1-\frac{(1-x)^2-u^2}{2(c-x)}$$
Let $u(x)=\frac{1}{v(x)}$
$$v'=\frac{(1-x)^2-2(c-x)}{2(c-x)}v^3-\frac{1}{2(c-x)}v$$
This is an Abel's differential equation of the first kind :
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbelsDifferentialEquation.html .

Don't confuse with Abel's differential equation identity.

To go further, see : https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1503/1503.05929.pdf
$$v(x)=\pm\sqrt{\frac{3(c-x)}{C_1+x(6c-x^2-3)}}$$

To be checked. This is an arduous calculus. Not sure about correctness.